# Communicate with Flash file in WebBrowser control C#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, flash

I am developing an windows application which have an Web Browser control.On some link Web Browser loads with an `.SWF` (flash file),in that flash one button is there with caption "Start" And when user clicks on this button then some animations get start.

I want that event when user clicks on "Start" button.
Can I do that?
I can't put any code in `.SWF` file.?
Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use ExternalInterface.  First, we need to import this new class so we can use it (as2 only, in as3 it will work without the import):

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
```

Next, we have to register any function we want to make available externally:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("addText", addText);
```

Basically, the code above will allow us to call the addText function (which I will show in a minute) from the C# application.
The addText function is as below. Basically, it takes a string input and appends it to a text box

```
function addText(val:String):void
{
      inTxt.appendText(val + "\n"); // append text recieved from c#
}
```

That's it from the ActionScript side. Now all we need to do is call the function from C#. First, I add an instance of the Flash Player ActiveX control to my form and load the SWF we created in the form's constructor:

```
private AxShockwaveFlash player;

public DemoForm ()
{
      ...
      player.LoadMovie(0,Application.StartupPath + "\\EITest.swf");
      player.Play();
      ...
 }
```

Next, all we have to do is call the externalized 
method when desired. In my case, it is in response to the user clicking the send button:

```
 private void sendBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     player.CallFunction("" + outTxt.Text + "");
  }
```

Comment: function addText(val:String):void method is in ActionScript,Correct?if yes then sorry i cant do this bcoz i cannot add any method in AS.